# What is the appropriate policy of backuping code repository for gitlab docker image?

Tags: linux, git, docker, gitlab

I have deployed a [genezys/gitlab](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/genezys/gitlab/) docker image on a host:

```
docker run --name gitlab_data genezys/gitlab:7.5.2 /bin/true
docker run --detach --name gitlab --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --volumes-from gitlab_data genezys/gitlab:7.5.2
```

Now I want to backup the code repository in case the host is crashed.

I am a little confused about the backup policy: Since I have created `gitlab_data` container for storage purpose, should I backup the whole `gitlab_data` docker image? Or I just use `gitlab rake` to backup the code repository? Or are there any better methods?

Comment: The important things is the **restore**, backup everything you need to do that restore in the time you have to do the restore. You should then try a restore to make sure you haven't missed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Only the [official backup process](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#creating-backups) should be needed.

Backup of the image should not: you would only docker run the *same* image again, with the right parameter to restore the app:

```
docker run --name=gitlab -it --rm [OPTIONS] \
  sameersbn/gitlab:7.10.1 app:rake gitlab:backup:restore
```

Backuping the image doesn't really make sense: the image should only be the app, which can be save and exported with docker save. Any persistent data should be backed up independently.
Plus:

- An application backup (like the `app:rake` task) isn't the same as "saving an image" (an image is just a filesystem).
  When you do an application backup (`app:rake` here), you can do additional jobs in order to ensure the consistency and integrity of the data you are about to backup. You are not simply compressing folders.
- [Thomasleveil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107049/thomasleveil) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026591/what-is-the-appropriate-policy-of-backuping-code-repository-for-gitlab-docker-im/30026987#comment48179399_30026987):

> You cannot backup your git repo by making a backup of the docker container into a docker image... because the gitlab image defines volumes for `/home/git/data` and `/var/log/gitlab`.
>   So any data written to those paths in the docker container IS NOT written on the docker container file system. As a result the `docker export` or `docker commit` commands would not include the content of those paths

In case of a data container, the OP adds:

> I use `docker commit` to save `gitlab_data` container as a new image, then restart the gitlab container using the new image as a volume, but find all the previous data doesn't exist (including code repository).

You don't restart gitlab with "the new (data) image": you need to create a container from that `gitlab_data_image` you have committed, and then restart gitlab using the `new_gitlab_data` container created from the committed `gitlab_data_image`.

```
docker create --name="new_gitlab_data" gitlab_data_image
docker run gitlab --volumes-from=new_gitlab_data
```

Comment: I use `docker commit` to save `gitlab_data` container as a new image, then restart the `gitlab` container using the new image as a volume, but find all the previous data doesn't exist (including code repository). Any comments or clues? Thanks!

Comment: @NanXiao you don't restart gitlab with "the new (data) image": you need to create a container from that image you have committed, and *then* restart gitlab using the new data *container* created from the committed image.

Comment: @VonC: Why the `gitlab` and `gitlab_data` should be the same image? I think the `gitlab_data` is just a storage.

Comment: @NanXiao I never say they were: one reference the other with the `--volumes-from` option.

Comment: @VonC: Sorry, I misunderstood your meaning. Yes, I think I do as you mentioned: (1) Create a new image: `docker commit e93cecab3c3c nanxiao:testimage`; (2) Remove all containers; (3) Use new image as storage: `docker run --name gitlab_data nanxiao:testimage /bin/true`; (4) Start new gitlab: `docker run --detach --name gitlab --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --volumes-from gitlab_data genezys/gitlab:7.5.2`. But no previous data can see, including the modified password. It seems a new clean `gitlab`.

Comment: Was e93cecab3c3c the SHA1 of the gitlab_data container?

Comment: @VonC: Yes, the container ID, from `docker ps -a` output.

Comment: @NanXiao cay you first do a `docker exec` to that data container and make sure that a ls shows some data?

Comment: @VonC: Yes, I have tried it in the morning. Now, I will try it for double check. Wait for a minute.

Comment: @VonC: There is no data in `/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/root/` after mounting the volume from new image. I have create a `test` repository before. So does it mean the data is not written into new image?

Comment: @VonC: Another phenomenon which confuses me: Executing the command `docker run --rm nanxiao:testimage [ -d /var/opt/gitlab/git-data ] && echo 'Directory found' || echo 'Directory not found'` outputs `Directory not found`. But the directory should be there.

Comment: @NanXiao the thing is; you are not mounting a volume from a image, but from a container. you need to docker create the container first (not docker run)

Comment: @VonC: `docker run` will create and run the container, right?

Comment: You don't need to run a data container, just to create it

Comment: @VonC: I use `docker create` command, but there is still no data. The same effect as `docker run`.

Comment: @NanXiao could you try with docker 1.6?

Comment: @VonC: Yes, I can try it. But it is too late today, I will build a new docker and try it tomorrow. Do you think it may be a bug?

Comment: @NanXiao maybe, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

### Additional information:

Data stored on a volume from a "data container" is not actually "in" the container. It is actually in a non-obvious directory on the host. So `docker commit` of the data container does not include the data stored on the volume.

To back up data from a Docker data container, you should mount a volume from the host and use `--volumes-from your_data_container` to access the data container data. Then copy from the data container to the mounted host volume. That process is described with more detail in the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes), but here is a shorthand version:

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdatadir
```

Where "dbdata" is your data container and "dbdatadir" is the location of the data you want to back up in the container.